# Invalid flag "testVisibility" in Autodesk Maya 2016

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm trying to determine if a set of mesh nodes is currently visible or not. Using pymel and [isVisible()](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/PyMel/generated/classes/pymel.core.nodetypes/pymel.core.nodetypes.DagNode.html?highlight=isvisible#pymel.core.nodetypes.DagNode.isVisible) works, but it's a huge performance hit.
Looking through the documentation, I found something that would (hopefully) solve my problem, the flag `testVisibility` on the Command [hide](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/hide.html).

According to the documentation the flag command will return a value that tells me if the specified nodes are visible or not.

The problem is, that flag doesn't exist.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.sphere(name='testsphere')
cmds.hide('testsphere', testVisibility = True)
```

Gives an error

```
# Error: Invalid flag 'testVisibility'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 4, in <module>
# TypeError: Invalid flag 'testVisibility' #
```

Same thing with the shortname of the flag "tv", as well as doing the whole thing in MEL: `hide -testVisibility;`.

The documentation includes this flag since Maya 2016. This is also the Maya version that I am using currently (more specifically, Maya 2016 SP5). Using the built-in link to the python documentation I arrive at the same documentation as I posted above. Looking through the changelog of SP6 doesn't mention anything of it either, so I assume it won't solve my problem.

I tried the same command on Maya 2017 and it works. That won't help me much though because that's not the Maya version that our team uses currently.

I can't contact Autodesk support because I'm not a subscriber (thanks autodesk, great help).

So my questions are:

- is there something that I'm missing/that I overlooked? Are these flags only implemented in some kind of super duper developer plugin? Do Maya versions only use the API of the previous versions or something?

  - is there a way to check if a command has a flag, without try-catching it?
  - any workarounds that are not as performance draining as the pymel route I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. I also tried `tv` flag for `hide` command and it definitely doesn't work.

Try setter/getter:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.sphere(name="testsphere")
cmds.setAttr("testsphere.visibility", False)
cmds.getAttr("testsphere.visibility")
```

I tested it in Maya 2016/2018.

```
# Result: False #
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to use the `visibility` attribute of nodes in the past, but it's not reliable (at least for my usecase). For example, if the node is nested the attribute won't help. The visibility could be `on`, but the parents are `off` and thus the result is misleading. I could walk the listRelatives upwards and check every single node myself, but I was hoping to not do this myself (and I suspect this is what pymel `isVisible()` is doing).

Comment: But I think your answer is correct regardless of my whining :-) There doesn't seem to be a way around it, so I will implement it myself and see if doing it in python only (as opposed to using pymel) speeds up the process at least a little bit.